# Can I estimate a panel VARX as a SUR?

Tags: panel-data, vector-autoregression, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

If my panel vector autoregression with exogenous variables (VARX) is unrestricted, and the same variables appear on every equation. Can I estimate it as a panel SUR?

Comment: Hi: If you have an autoregression ( I'm not familiar with panel vector autoregression ), then you should have the same variable on both sides of each equation. Assuming that's the case, then you can't estimate a SUR, atleast not directly. Note that,  as an aside,in the standard SUR, if the same variables appear in every equation, then the SUR can be reduced to OLS on each equation ( because SUR doesn't add anything when all the variables are in all of the equations ). See luktepohl's text for the details and proof.

Comment: @mlofton, what is the reasoning behind *...you should have the same variable on both sides of each equation. Assuming that's the case, then you can't estimate a SUR*? Why would having the same variable (actually, not quite; these are different lags of the same time series) on both sides preclude that?

Comment: Hi Richard: What I meant was: Suppose he-she has say a variable $x_t$ on both sides of the equation  so that $x_t$ is on the LHS and $x_{t-1}$ say is on the RHS, Then he-she can't run a regression or atleast if he-she runs one, it will be biased because a regression doesn't expect lags of the same variable on the RHS. I'm sorry for confusion.

Comment: @mlofton, *all* of the standard estimators will be biased in an autoregressive model, so this is not a great argument for avoiding a specific estimator. But I think SUR will be consistent, and that is good enough. Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, all standard estimators will be biased which is why I said that converting the panelled vector autoregressive model to a SUR is probably not a good idea. If I was the OP, I'd probably look at numerical methods for solving panel vector ARs rather than converting it to a SUR. I bet one of the academics who specialize in panel vector AR's have proposed some kind of numerical algorithm analogous to the numerical algorithms for plain ( not panelled ) vector AR's.  But we can agree to disagree !!!!! I don't know enough about panelled data to be certain about my bet.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: Just to close out my attempt to help the OP, the paper below is the first thing I would read if I was trying to figure out the best way to estimate a panel VAR. http://apps.eui.eu/Personal/Canova/workingpapers/panel_var_final_3.pdf